# Python | Split string and receive two list, but delimiter still exist in last index

Tags: python, regex

So my problem is how do I split string but the last index of that splat string have no delimiter and the first index has it, using the `split` string or any method

If you're still confused, here is the example:

```
ret = "Hello, World, Test".split(',', 1)
# ret = ['Hello', ' World, Test']
```

That code gives us `['Hello', ' World, Test']`, but that's not what I want it

What I want is the reversed of it, so it will become like this `['Hello, World', ' Test']`

I tried this but it doesn't work because `maxsplit` is already `1`

```
ret = "Hello, World, Test".split(',', -1)
#ret = ['Hello', ' World', ' Test']
```

But it doesn't not work and gives `['Hello', ' World', ' Test']`

Another example is this

```
ret = 'My name is Faran'.split(maxsplit=1)
#ret = ['My', 'name is Faran']
```

The example of above return `['My', 'name is Faran']`, what I want is `['My name is', 'Faran']`

Here is the part of the real code

```
try:
 subj = ''.join([a+' ' for a in SecOperator if ' '+a+' ' in rcmd.strip().lower()]).strip().split(' ')[0]
 op = [i.strip() for i in rcmd.strip().split(subj, 1)]
 rcmd = (SecOperator[subj] + ' ' + op[0].strip() + ', ' + op[1]).strip()
except:
 pass
```

Where the `op` is the list that I want and I showed to you

Comment: Do you mean `"Hello, World, Test".rsplit(',', 1)` ?

Comment: thanks buddy, i search it and found it lol :D. but thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `rsplit` function. It works like the `split` function, but it starts searching for the delimiter from the right end of the string.

```
ret = "Hello, World, Test".rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
import re
ret = 'My name is Faran'
k = ret.split(' ')[-1]
my_list = []
my_list.append(ret.replace(k,''))
my_list.append(k)
print(my_list)
```

output will be :

```
['My name is ', 'Faran']
```